# How to set up trade chests with command blocks in minecraft 1.14?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to trade certain items in my inventory for other items, using command blocks in minecraft 1.14. For example, trading in 32x charcoal for 1x diamond, as if using a machine to compress the carbon. The only problem is that the guides/vids I find use /testfor.

Answer (score 0):

/testfor has been removed in 1.13 as it has been replaced by /execute which is much more useful. In the old days, you would have to take a comparator output from /testfor or /testforblock to see if the thing that was tested for was True. So basically you could only have boolean data. With execute, you can do everything like that but also store entity targets right away in the same command. Especially the new 1.13 system has made execute so powerful. Check out some videos on 1.13 command system **brigadier**.

As for this system, you could do something like this on a repeat command block. There are still problems with this clearly. You could improve it by just checking for more things.

```
/execute positioned <chest location> if data block ~ ~ ~ {Items:[{id:"minecraft:coal",Count:32b}]} run data merge block ~ ~ ~ {Items:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b}]}
```